# Sonata Admin: Want to create global configuration page

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3, symfony-sonata

I need to create signle global configuration page without list view, just single page with number of inputs like:

- fb page link
- google analytics id
- some default front-end texts
- checkbox options: show intro, show social media etc.

something that doesn't require to go through record listing, edit, save and return to list etc.

Do i need to create new controller with form and my own crud?
Or is there a way to nicely connect/override sonata admin with that kind of panel?

I'm using:

- Symfony 2.3.X Latest
- Sonata cache 2.1.5
- Sonata block 2.2.7
- Sonata easy-extends 2.1.4
- Sonata admin 2.2.8
- Sonata doctrine-orm-admin 2.2.5
- Sonata jquery 1.8.*@dev
- Sonata intl 2.2.*@dev
- Sonata user 2.2.*@dev
- Sonata media 2.2.*@dev
- Sonata page 2.3.*@dev
- Sonata seo 1.1.*@dev
- Stof Doctrine Extensions Latest

**EDIT**

Following answer of pulzarraider and some more search i ended up with overriding listAction of CRUD controller.

In details, first created service definition (YML):

```
services:
    stack.admin.global_administration:
        class: Stack\Bundle\SiteBundle\Admin\GlobalConfigurationAdmin
        tags:
            - name: sonata.admin
              manager_type: orm
              group: Administration
              label: Global Configuration
        arguments:
            - ~
            - ~
            - StackSiteBundle:GlobalConfiguration
```

Then created Admin class for this specific action:

```
<?php
namespace stack\Bundle\SiteBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class GlobalConfigurationAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected $baseRouteName = 'global-configuration';
    protected $baseRoutePattern = 'global-admin';

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        // notice removal of create action!
        $collection->remove('create');
    }
}
?>
```

And finally CRUD controller to display custom form instead of default entity list action:

```
<?php 
namespace Stack\Bundle\SiteBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class GlobalConfigurationController extends Controller
{
    public function listAction()
    {
        if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('LIST')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        // custom code here...

        return $this->render('StackSiteBundle:Administration:configuration-view.html.twig', array(
            'action' => 'list',
            'csrf_token' => $this->getCsrfToken('sonata.batch')
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for help with this one!

Comment: thanks for sharing the answer, but can you pls also share the content of this page `StackSiteBundle:Administration:configuration-view.html.twig` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it`s possible in Sonata Admin by overloading default CRUD controller.

You must create custom controller and overload `editAction`.
In editAction you can create standard Symfony form, process the data from user and save it anywhere you want.

Comment: That gave me two hints what to do but i ended up overriding listAction as i needed to show custom form right AFTER you choose item from top menu. That did the trick. Later on i might post code how to do it.

Comment: @ShachMaT - Apparently, you did not find the time to post the code. You missed an opportunity to share back to the community.

Comment: @roelleor yes shame on me. Even though i posted the "code", so thank you for smacking me over head ;) for being late.